# Cant print dictionary in python as a function return with correct format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a function which works but I can't get it to return the output in the desired format.

My code:

```
def readingjunk(filename):
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    dicty = {} 
    for line in infile:
          words = line.split()
          words = line.rsplit()
          #words = getWord(words)
          #print(words)
          for word in words :
                if word not in dicty:
                      dicty[word] = 1
    dicty.pop("/#")
    dicty.pop("#/")
    dicty2 = {}
    nobr = []
    for item in dicty.items():
          if(item[0] == getWord(item[0])):
             #print(item[0])
             nobr.append(item[0])
             dicty2[item[0]] = 1
    #nobr = str(nobr)
    #nobr.lower()
    #for item in dicty2.items() :
     #     print(item[0])  
    #print(dicty2)
    infile.close()
    return(print(dicty2))
```

The output looks like:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, "D": 1, "E": 1}
```

I want the output to look like this in alphabetical order and lowercase:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I've tried to get round this but need help.

Comment: `print(*sorted(map(str.lower, dicty2)), sep='\n')`. You don't need to use `return` here at all, `print()` produces `None`, no point in returning that result. And `return` is not a function, don't use `(..)` parentheses there.

Comment: Note that you don't need *any of the code you posted*, it is entirely irrelevant to the problem you have described. You could just have put `dicty2 = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, "D": 1, "E": 1}` and `print(dicty2)` in the question and that'd have been enough to describe the input.

Comment: Instead post irreverent code post what is the relation between dictionary and output .

Comment: print(*sorted(map(str.lower, dicty2)), sep='\n') this produces none if I try putting into a file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can print the output with:

```
dicty2 = {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, "D": 1, "E": 1}
for key in sorted(dicty2.keys()):
    print(key.lower())
```

---

**Please don't use the code below.**

Comments are based on:

```
[print(key.lower()) for key in sorted(dicty2.keys())]
```

Comment: List comprehension should not just be used for their side affects. This also produces a list full of `None`s. It would be better to just use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: a generator would be an better option, or?

Comment: No, not really. Not only will the print statements not be executed, as generator expressions are lazy, but that would still produce an unneeded generator expression. As I said in my previous comment, simply using a regular for loop would be the best solution(or you could do what @MartijnPieters did, but that's beside the point).